# How to query the date format YYYY-MM-dd HH-MM-ss?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to query the date with the format :

02/13/2013  12:05:48

```
select * 
from TOTAL_SUBS 
where TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('2013-13-02 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
AND TO_DATE('2013-12-14 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

I have try with that code but what i expected from the date only came out the 02/13/2013, There is no Time "12:05:48" came out in the result.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no a month with the number of 13

Comment: 12:05 , youexpect from which day 14th?

Comment: If you are able to filter out this date using this select statement then definitely timestamp is there. You can check that by selecting `to_char(time, 'RRRR-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS)` from the table. If NLS date format is set to a format in which timestamp is not specified, it won't show up in the tool where you are querying it. Moreover '2013-13-02 00:00:00' is not a valid month.

Comment: What application do you use ? if Oracle SQL Developer, you just need to go to Tools menu -> Database -> NLS. Add the date format as you wish. Without this, no matter how the query structure is, it will never show the time

Comment: First off, don't use `BETWEEN` [with timestamps](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common), or any other variable-precision type either (essentially, anything but an integer count, and I'd avoid it there too for consistency reasons).  Date/time types don't really have formats - what's the actual type of `TIME`?

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT**: It advisable to do to_char() to requirement format, as the NLS_DATE_FORMAT may not be same everywhere you run your Query!

If, at all you want to change NLS, please do this.

```
alter session set nls_date_format='MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS';
```

Finally, a TO_CHAR() conversion in the select. Actually, when you want print(see) a DATE datatype in the format you expect, use this.

```
select * , TO_CHAR(TIME,'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') my_datetime
from TOTAL_SUBS 
where TIME BETWEEN TO_DATE('2013-02-13 00:00:00', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
AND TO_DATE('2013-12-14 23:59:59', 'SYYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

Edited the month and the timestamp to include till mdnight. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

What application do you use ?

if Oracle SQL Developer, you just need to go to Tools menu -> Database -> NLS.

Add the date format as you wish.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   total_subs 
WHERE  time BETWEEN To_date('2013-02-13 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') AND 
                    To_date('2013-12-14 00:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS');
```

Try your query again.

Without this, no matter how the query structure is, it will never show the time