# how to insert data using trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, ddl

I got question about using trigger to insert data, for instance, I do have two tables, and second table has attributes and records with table, except additional two attributes, like below:

```
CREATE TABLE dept
( 
    DEPTNO NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    DNAME VARCHAR2(16),
    LOC VARCHAR2(16) 
);

CREATE TABLE dept_shadow
( 
    DEPTNO  NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    DNAME   VARCHAR2(16),
    LOC     VARCHAR2(16),
    USER    VARCHAR2(32),
    MODTIME CHAR(17)
);
```

and I want create a trigger to track all inserts into a table.

surprisedly, I got error about creating table:

```
Error starting at line : 11 in command -
CREATE TABLE dept_shadow
( 
    DEPTNO  NUMBER(3) PRIMARY KEY,
    DNAME   VARCHAR2(16),
    LOC     VARCHAR2(16),
    USER    VARCHAR2(32),
    MODTIME CHAR(17)
)
Error report -
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

I have no idea about this error and does anyone can tell me how to do this job by create trigger? Since there is no actual records to insert! Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: `user` is a reserved keyword. Don't use it as a column (or table) name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so the error you are getting is because oracle (like all databases) has some reserved words. Now I'm not 100% sure because I don't tend to work with Oracle DB all that often, but I would assume that you cannot use the word `USER` for that reason. Try using `USERNAME` or `USERDESCRIPTION` or something like that instead.

Now for the trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER trg_shadow
   BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE
   ON dept_shadow
   REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
   FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
   MODTIME   char (17);
BEGIN
   IF INSERTING
   THEN
      -- do something
   ELSIF UPDATING
   THEN
      -- do something
   ELSIF DELETING
   THEN
      -- do something
   END IF;
```

From there, you can access "new" data through :`NEW` and "old" data through `:OLD`.

**EDIT:**

The difference of a `BEFORE` and `AFTER` trigger is when they are executed and both have a valid use.

`BEFORE` triggers may be used to validate data BEFORE inserting or updating. So for instance if you don't want to update the rows that would otherwise have the value 0 in column x.

`AFTER` triggers may be used to validate the new data AFTER inserting. So for instance if you want to delete all rows that now have the value 0 in column x.

It doesn't really matter in your case though.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Indeed, `USER` is a reserved word.  See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/ap_keywd001.htm#SQLRF55621).

Comment: @Xaphas Thank you so much for your answer! Yes the name of attributes is problem

Comment: @Xaphas, cannot appreciate more for your help in this question. So in this case, if the trigger insert a duplicate record into the DEPT_SHADOW table along with the information of the USER who performs the insertion, also the date/time of the insertion, how do I keep track of the date/time in the MM/DD/YY hh:mm:ss format?

Comment: @SteveShi check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035610/how-to-query-the-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-hh-mm-ss) out for datetime formatting.

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of the column name(`user`) you are using in the `dept_shadow` table.
USER is predefined that's why it won't work as column name in table. Rename it to 'audit_user' or anything you want, which is not keyword. It will work seamlessly.

And for trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER dept_trigger
AFTER INSERT
   ON dept
   FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE
   v_username varchar2(10);

BEGIN
   -- Find username of person performing the INSERT into the table
   SELECT user INTO v_username
   FROM dual;

   -- Insert record into shadow table
   INSERT INTO dept_shadow
   ( DEPTNO,
     DNAME,
     LOC,
     AUDIT_USER,
     MODTIME )
   VALUES
   ( :new.DEPTNO,
     :new.DNAME,
     :new.LOC,
     v_username, 
     :new.MODTIME
   );
END;
/
```

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: That really make sense! Thank you soo much!

Comment: @ Arif Sher Khan another question: comparing with answer from @Xaphas, may I ask you guys question about this: why you use after, but Xaphas using before?

Comment: place for trigger is in table definition for SQL server databases?

Comment: @SteveShi It basically defines when the trigger will be fired. 
You can refer [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3646110/difference-before-and-after-trigger-in-oracle) for in depth.

Comment: @KubaDo Although I am not sure about SQL Server, but I understand that they are defined separately, and not in table definition.

Comment: @ArifSherKhan - thanks, I just did some research, its in different place as You wrote.